# Vulkan Instance APIVersion versus Vulkan Device APIVersion

Tags: instance, device, vulkan

I have a notebook with 2 graphics devices.  My Vulkan Instance is APIversion 1.3.  One Vulkan device driver is version 1.3 and the other driver is 1.2.

I want to use VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY on both devices.  VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY was promoted to core in 1.3 but was available via an extension (VK_EXT_extended_dynamic_state) before 1.3.

Using the version 1.3 device I can call vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopology without loading the extension and it works as I expected.

However, on the APIversion 1.2 device, I load the extension but the call to vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopology fails.  I thought that maybe I need to call vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopologyEXT, as this was the call provided when this dynamic state was first released.  However, this call is set to NULL during the connecting to the Vulkan Library.  So with this combination I cannot use the dynamic state.

How do I use the VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY dynamic state with this Instance v1.3/Device v1.2 combination?  Does the Device APIVersion need to match the Instance APIVersion??

Comment: *"However, this call is set to NULL during the connecting to the Vulkan Library."* How are you "connecting" to the vulkan loader? Are you using the automatic binding/the OS provided *get* functions, or are you using [vkGetDeviceProcAddr](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkGetDeviceProcAddr.html). You probably can't use either of the former, you have to use the latter for this function.

Comment: I am using the vkGetProcAddress for both vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopology and vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopologyEXT

Comment: Presumably that should work; can we see the code you're using to load in the functions. Is the debug layer giving you any information about why this might be failing?

Comment: Please see below.. as you can see I am using pascal.  The validation layer does not return anything and the app fails with an invalid memory read.

Comment: if not assigned(vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopology) then begin
   @vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopology:=vkVoidFunctionToPointer(vkGetProcAddress(LibVulkan,'vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopology'));
  end;

Comment: if not assigned( (vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopologyEXT) then begin @vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopologyEXT:=vkVoidFunctionToPointer(vkGetProcAddress(LibVulkan,'vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopologyEXT'));

Comment: Apologies,  I have looked further and the library I use calls GetProcAddress inside the vkGetProcAddress for loading Global functions (which the library currently includes vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopology and vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopologyEXT).  The library also has sections for loading InstanceCommands and DeviceCommands.  Should the vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopology be loaded as Instance or Device commands??

Comment: Being a command function, it is part of a device, but it can be loaded with either the instance loader or device loader, with the caveat that if you load it with the instance loader you will get a small additional overhead for dynamic dispatch. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948159/about-function-loader-in-vulkan

Comment: On further investigation, it seems the library loads the command (vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopology and vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopologyEXT at the Global level, the Instance level and the Device level.  If I use the Device level commands, then it behaves as I would expect.. for v1.2 Device the vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopologyEXT is valid and works (vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopology is NULL) and for the v1.3 Device the vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopology is valid and works (as does the vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopologyEXT).  Thanks for the guidance.